# Different compositions with nearly the same values

Tags: analysis

Consider the following compositions

$$\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\sin(1))))) = 0.7605544662971730378084837618$$

$$\cos(\sin(\cos(\cos(\sin(1))))) = 0.7599347639070954684181715364$$

The length of such a composition (the argument is always $1$) is the number of $\cos$- and
$\sin$-operations (in the above example $5$). The object is to find the two different
compositions with a given length, such that the difference of the values is as small
as possible. Of course, the answer can be found with brute force, the above example is
optimal for length $5$.

Questions : 1) Is there an effective way to find the optimal solution ?

2) Does the optimal difference tend to $0$, when $n$ tends to infinity ?

Comment: ? s=15;o=vector(2^s);for(l=0,2^s-1,w=binary(l);for(j=1,s-length(w),w=concat(0,w)
);x=1;for(j=1,s,if(w[j]==0,x=cos(x));if(w[j]==1,x=sin(x)));o[l+1]=x);mini=1;for(
i=1,2^s,for(j=i+1,2^s,dif=abs(o[i]-o[j]);if(dif<mini,mini=dif;print(i-1," ",j-1,
"  ",dif))))

Comment: Above the PARI program searching for length 15

Comment: 14922 29280  4.270873580796048754837362986 E-9  is the result.

Comment: The compositions are coded in binary form with leading zeros.

Comment: you may like to look at this question i asked a few days ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581278/conjecture-regarding-the-cosine-fixed-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to second part of the question is affirmative -- the difference indeed goes down to zero.

In order to see why, it suffices to realize that repeated applications of $\cos(x)$ lead to a fixed point $A$ such that $\cos(A)=A$, regardless of the starting point. Now, consider sequences defined as $$a_0 = \cos 1 \\ a_n = \cos a_{n-1}$$ and $$b_0 = \sin 1 \\ b_n = \cos b_{n-1}$$ Both of them necessarily converge to $A$, so their difference goes to zero with growing $n$. Since both sequences correspond to valid $\cos$/$\sin$ expressions, their difference provides upper bound on the optimal one, which must thus also go to zero.

It's possible to get an explicit numerical estimate on this upper bound. We have $$|a_n - b_n| = |\cos a_{n-1} - \cos b_{n-1}|$$
Mean-value theorem tells us that there is some $c$ between $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$ such that $$|\cos a_{n-1} - \cos b_{n-1}| = |a_{n-1} - b_{n-1}|\cdot|\sin c|$$
Since $a_n, b_n\in [0,1]$, we have $|\sin c|\leq \sin 1 \approx 0.8415$. Therefore, the difference $|a_n-b_n|$ decreases (at least) by factor $0.8415$ at every step. The actual rate of decrease is even faster than that; as we get closer to $A$, the interval for $c$ gets more and more narrow too and the factor of decrease gets closer to $\sin A\approx 0.6736$.

Note that this all is just an upper bound; the actual optimal difference is likely to decrease considerably faster.

When it comes to searching for the optimum, I don't see any algorithm better than brute-force search. However, it's possible to optimize the algorithm provided a bit (at least when it comes to time complexity)

```
s=15;v=[1];for(k=1,s,v=concat(cos(v),sin(v)));
v=vecsort(v);d=1;for(i=2,#v,d=min(d,v[i]-v[i-1]));print(d)
```

The first line computes vector of $2^s$ entries consisting of values of all possible $\cos$/$\sin$ expressions of length $s$, when applied to initial value $1$ ($\sin$ and $\cos$ operations applied to a vector get applied to all elements of that vector). This vector is then sorted in order to find the minimum difference between consecutive entries (clearly, the optimum must be between two consecutive values). Done this way, we only obtain the optimal difference; although if one needs the actual expressions, it's not too difficult to recover them too -- either by storing them along with the value of the expression, or by re-running the value-generator. Being faster should allow you to extend the search up to $n=20$ or so; when the memory requirements become too high.